# Only allow specific set values only

Tags: javascript

I have a form, I m trying to only allow certain values when submitted.
Allowed is 1-8, n and blank. That is all.
I have started on 1-8 but for n and blank I dont know.

```
function check(form) {
    if (form.scores.value > 8 || form.scores.value <= 0) {
        self.alert(form.scores.value + " is an invalid value! Allowed values are 1 to 8, n and blank");
        form.scores.focus();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="scores" id="scores" maxlength="1" size="2" value="<%= number %>" />
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onClick="check(this.form)" value="Edit" />
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "n"? The string `"n"`?

Comment: if you want from 1 to 8, N and blank, why not use listbox?

Comment: yes string n. cant work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below refactor and fix.

```
<script>

function check(form_field)
{

  var allowed = /^[1-8n\s]{1}$/;

  var field = document.getElementById(form_field).value;

  if (field.match(allowed)) {
    document.myform.onsubmit = function() {
     return true;
    }
  } else if (field.length == 0) {
    document.myform.onsubmit = function() {
     return true;
    }
  } else {
   alert(field + " is an invalid value! Allowed values are 1 to 8, n and blank");
  }

}

</script>


<form name="myform" onsubmit="return false">

<input type="text" name="scores" id="scores" maxlength="1" size="2" value="<%= number %>"/>
<input type="submit" onClick="check('scores')" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

Uses javascripts regex to check for the values. The "{1}"  might not be needed though as a pattern repeated once is obv just the pattern.

Feel free to just grab the regex part as I have changed the mechanics of the check() function so it is handed the forms field ID and it identifies the values from that.

It makes sure it only submits the form if the conditions are all met.

EDIT:
Alternatively check out [listbox](http://plugins.jquery.com/listbox/) for a nice jquery plugin to do this (as mentioned by @Ark)

Hope that helps

Comment: I was assuming blank was `""`, not `" "`.